# Как через PHP сравнить текст и ответ от сервера и вывести указанное значение?

Tags: php

Как через PHP сравнить текст и ответ от сервера и вывести указанное значение?
Нужно, чтобы сервер сравнил переменную с отображаемым
Пользуюсь вот этой самописным выдуманным выражением, в php практически нуль, откорректируйте, пожалуйста, потому что не работает на моем сайте, отображает второе следствие всегда.

```html
<?php 
$a = krd.site.ru;
$b = site.ru; 
if ($a == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {   // Вот тут я сомневаюсь в переменной $_SERVER
 echo 'Краснодаре';
}
 else {
 echo 'Санкт-Петербурге';
}
  
?>
```

Comment: Почему? $_SERVER - супер-глобальная переменная которая есть практически везде только если к PHP Вы не обращаетесь из консоли. Если PHP как модуль Вашего Веб-сервера то массив $_SERVER будет понятен и заполнен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = 'krd.site.ru';
$b = 'site.ru';
```

Когда вы строку без кавычек записываете она интерпретируется как константа.